# SSD: Support for SATA 3.1 and "queued TRIM"

Tags: kernel, ssd

I have a relatively new Thinkpad 530 running Xubuntu 13.04. I want to swap out the drive with a SSD and am considering the Samsung 840 series.

There are three models (Pro, non-Pro and EVO).  The newest is the EVO with *SATA 3.1* and *queued trim* support, review [here](http://www.anandtech.com/show/7173/samsung-ssd-840-evo-review-120gb-250gb-500gb-750gb-1tb-models-tested).

Does the 3.8 kernel (that I am running) support "SATA 3.1" and "queued TRIM"? If so, the EVO controller seems like a huge win.

If not, I'll fall back to the non-Pro drive as - although I'm using the box as a development workstation - shelling out another $100 for the Pro doesn't seem worth it, and I gather the non-Pro 840 works well with GNU/Linux.

Answer (score 4):

- Queued Trim is going into v3.12-rc1 of the kernel. See: https://lkml.org/lkml/2013/9/3/277
- Unless you're running a full queue depth a majority of the time, queued trim commands won't buy you much.